# How to autoupdate Phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I want to get rid of updates through Google Play and AppStore.
Instead, I would like my application to be fetched by the mobile clients automatically.

Does any one know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you would have to make some kind of bootstrap code which would not be update-able without AppStore/Play, but that part would fetch any html/js/css/... files via FileTransfer.download() to your cache folder and then include them in the main html which would otherwise be empty.
eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And now in your bootstrap.js use requestFileSystem and co. to get access to a cache folder where you will download any additional stuff you want to execute and then add it to the html and execute, possibly something like https://github.com/mmarcon/jquery-on-demand
Adding content to the html to load from your local cache is simple, just say file://+full_path_to_your_file when adding content src, or just load and .append() it to the html. Basically it's like writing self modifying code.

Now there is a whole other story would that be okay by AppStore & co that you update your app without their approval... It's okay for content but not sure for code, but on the other hand this is no native code, just js so I presume that could be okay, but this requires more research.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova-standalone-hydration does exactly that,  you can find it here:

https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-standalone-hydration

Hope it helps, if you have any questions feel free to let me know, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Is this "legal" according to Apple's rules? Have you deployed apps to the app store that use this successfully?